# Create Javascript Button in VF Component

Tags: javascript, visualforce-component

Is it possible to create a custom button (*similar to onclick custom button on page layout*) that invokes javascript ?

Comment: You can use a normal visualforce in the component, and `apex:commandButton` with `onclick="myJavaScriptFunction();"` attribute for sure.

Comment: @mastor: but the function should end with `return false;` or have it slapped after the function call in onclick or the event will still do what commandButtons do. If there's no `action` specified commandbuttons just go to server, fire getters/setters without other methods being called and refresh the page...

Answer (score 2):

You can add a regular html input element to the page and mimic standard button's look&feel by adding '**btn**' class:

```
<input type="button" class="btn" value="JS Invoking button" onclick="alert('Say hello or invoke some js function!');"  />
```